# Are iocb requests passed to kernel evaluated in order or not?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, aio

I read 2 posts related to Linux AIO (native AIO).

1. https://blog.cloudflare.com/io_submit-the-epoll-alternative-youve-never-heard-about/

> It's important to note the `iocb` requests passed to kernel are evaluated in-order sequentially.

2. https://github.com/littledan/linux-aio

> `io_submit` allows an array of pointers to `struct iocbs` to be submitted all at once. In this function call, `nr` is the length of the `ios` array. If multiple operations are sent in one array, then no ordering guarantees are given between the `iocb`s.

The 2. article uses `#include <liaio.h>` and as far as I know, it's merely a wrapper of Linux AIO system calls. So I am confused why one of the articles says "in-order" while another says "no ordering guarantees"?

Which description is wrong? It would be appreciated if someone could provide a code snippet to test.

Comment: The manual page for the system call [`io_submit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/io_submit.2.html) indicates that (a) GLIBC does not provide a cover function for this system call and (b) you should probably be using `-laio`, a library, which does provide a slightly different function interface to this system call.  It also does not specify the (important) detail you want to know about, AFAICS.  I've not managed to track down what I regard as definitive information for the `libaio` library.  The best I've found (and not read) is for [ArchLinux](https://man.archlinux.org/man/io.3.en).

Comment: A cursory examination of the Linux kernel source at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/aio.c sure seems to support the assertion that even though **A**IO stands for **asynchronous** IO, Linux performs the IO operations sequentially when submitted via `io_submit()`. I don't know offhand whether or not Linux fully supports true asynchronous IO via POSIX-standard calls such as [`lio_listio()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/lio_listio.html).

Comment: There's a new game in town (since May 2019, or thereabouts): Wikipedia describes the [io_uring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_uring) system calls.  It is meant to be a replacement for `io_submit()` et al, available from kernel 5.1.